# How do I get display:inline-block to be inline?

Tags: css

```
<ul class="random-list">
   <li>
       <div class="random-container">
           <div class="inline-block" style="vertical-align: top;">
               <img src="" />
           </div>
           <div class="inline-block" style="vertical-align: top;">
               <a href="">Name</a>
           </div>
       </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And css:

```
.random-container {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Result:

[image: Error]

How to fix this error:

[image: Fix]

Comment: Which is the expected result, and which is the actual result?

Answer (score 6):

How about you don't use `inline-block` at all, and get rid of all of those unnecessary divs.

```
<ul class="random-list">
   <li>
       <img src="" />
       <a href="">Name</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**[Live Example](http://dabblet.com/gist/3016529)**

Answer (score 1):

Giving both elements a float: left would be a better option. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLUhL/).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have enough space on your screen? Your code works for me as it works in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLUhL/2/):

That said: another +1 goes to Truth's answer. Theres no need to use so many `div`s you're currently using.

Comment: Probably browser dependent since display: inline-block; doesn't work on older IE's.

Comment: @Damien Forgot to mention I tested only using old Firefox and new Safari. Can't be bothered with IE...

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="random-list">
   <li>
       <img src=""/>
       <a href="">Name</a>
   </li>
</ul>

#random-list
{
   float:left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey now according your design

you give to **li** properties  `display:block;`

as like this

```
li{
display:block;
}
```

or this

```
.random-list li{
display:block;
}
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/GrZLW/